# Jquery Ui Tab call backs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some tabs that I load the content up via ajax. I am wondering is there away to look at the response of the ajax call before it loads the content into the tabs?

I want to see if any errors occurred. For instance the tab contents might need the users Id but for some reason that was null. In my code that I have I have stuff that actually checks for these things and if this happens puts it in a validation error.

I usually return the errors back as a json result and use a dialog box to display the error.

So I would like to check the ajax call from the tab and see if it is a validation error(json response) and if has validation errors stop loading the tab and popup a dialog box.

So does jquery ui tabs have something like this? Or do I have to use http status code and set a status code error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ajaxOptions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-ajaxOptions) to supply a complete function which will allow you to look inside the response. The exact args passed to the [complete event](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) depend on which version of jQuery you are using.

```
function checkResponse(args){

   //interrogate the response and decide what to show the user

}

$( ".tabs" ).tabs({ ajaxOptions: { complete: checkResponse } });
```

Comment: I am using 1.5. So will the data be loaded into the tab at this point?

Comment: @chobo2 -  not at the complete stage, The tabs use the success event to populate the contents.